# Weird blank space next to navbar Bootstrap5

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

After building this layout with a left-sided nav-bar menu, I found that a weird blank space is left between the navbar and the main content area. Does anyone know why that space appears and how to take it away?

Here is the code snippet: https://bbbootstrap.com/snippets/bootstrap-5-sidebar-menu-toggle-button-34132202

[image: Error photo]

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

  const showNavbar = (toggleId, navId, bodyId, headerId) => {
    const toggle = document.getElementById(toggleId),
      nav = document.getElementById(navId),
      bodypd = document.getElementById(bodyId),
      headerpd = document.getElementById(headerId)

    // Validate that all variables exist
    if (toggle && nav && bodypd && headerpd) {
      toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
        // show navbar
        nav.classList.toggle('show')
        // change icon
        toggle.classList.toggle('bx-x')
        // add padding to body
        bodypd.classList.toggle('body-pd')
        // add padding to header
        headerpd.classList.toggle('body-pd')
      })
    }
  }

  showNavbar('header-toggle', 'nav-bar', 'body-pd', 'header')

  /*===== LINK ACTIVE =====*/
  const linkColor = document.querySelectorAll('.nav_link')

  function colorLink() {
    if (linkColor) {
      linkColor.forEach(l => l.classList.remove('active'))
      this.classList.add('active')
    }
  }
  linkColor.forEach(l => l.addEventListener('click', colorLink))

  // Your code to run since DOM is loaded and ready
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap");
:root {
  --header-height: 3rem;
  --nav-width: 68px;
  --first-color: #4723D9;
  --first-color-light: #AFA5D9;
  --white-color: #F7F6FB;
  --body-font: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  --normal-font-size: 1rem;
  --z-fixed: 100
}

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: var(--header-height) 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  font-family: var(--body-font);
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  transition: .5s
}

a {
  text-decoration: none
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--header-height);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  background-color: var(--white-color);
  z-index: var(--z-fixed);
  transition: .5s
}

.header_toggle {
  color: var(--first-color);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer
}

.header_img {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden
}

.header_img img {
  width: 40px
}

.l-navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -30%;
  width: var(--nav-width);
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
  padding: .5rem 1rem 0 0;
  transition: .5s;
  z-index: var(--z-fixed)
}

.nav {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: hidden
}

.nav_logo,
.nav_link {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  padding: .5rem 0 .5rem 1.5rem
}

.nav_logo {
  margin-bottom: 2rem
}

.nav_logo-icon {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  color: var(--white-color)
}

.nav_logo-name {
  color: var(--white-color);
  font-weight: 700
}

.nav_link {
  position: relative;
  color: var(--first-color-light);
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  transition: .3s
}

.nav_link:hover {
  color: var(--white-color)
}

.nav_icon {
  font-size: 1.25rem
}

.show {
  left: 0
}

.body-pd {
  padding-left: calc(var(--nav-width) + 1rem)
}

.active {
  color: var(--white-color)
}

.active::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: var(--white-color)
}

.height-100 {
  height: 100vh
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  body {
    margin: calc(var(--header-height) + 1rem) 0 0 0;
    padding-left: calc(var(--nav-width) + 2rem)
  }
  .header {
    height: calc(var(--header-height) + 1rem);
    padding: 0 2rem 0 calc(var(--nav-width) + 2rem)
  }
  .header_img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px
  }
  .header_img img {
    width: 45px
  }
  .l-navbar {
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem 1rem 0 0
  }
  .show {
    width: calc(var(--nav-width) + 156px)
  }
  .body-pd {
    padding-left: calc(var(--nav-width) + 188px)
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="./css/navlayout.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boxicons@latest/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="icon" href="./img/icon.png" />

  <title>Basic - Bootstrap 5 with Gulp 4</title>
</head>

<body id="body-pd">
  <header class="header" id="header">
    <div class="header_toggle"> <i class='bx bx-menu' id="header-toggle"></i> </div>
    <div class="header_img"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/hczKIze.jpg" alt=""> </div>
  </header>
  <div class="l-navbar" id="nav-bar">
    <nav class="nav">
      <div>
        <a href="#" class="nav_logo"> <i class='bx bx-layer nav_logo-icon'></i> <span class="nav_logo-name">BBBootstrap</span> </a>
        <div class="nav_list">
          <a href="#" class="nav_link active"> <i class='bx bx-grid-alt nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">Dashboard</span> </a>
          <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class='bx bx-user nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">Users</span> </a>
          <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class='bx bx-message-square-detail nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">Messages</span> </a>
          <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class='bx bx-bookmark nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">Bookmark</span> </a>
          <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class='bx bx-folder nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">Files</span> </a>
          <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class='bx bx-bar-chart-alt-2 nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">Stats</span> </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class='bx bx-log-out nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">SignOut</span> </a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <!--Container Main start-->
  <div class="height-100 bg-light">
    <h4>Main Components</h4>
  </div>
  <!--Container Main end-->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="./js/navlayout.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: It might be related to the body padding you're applying programmatically. Please revise your post to explain what that code is intended to do. Bootstrap has a sidebar component built in. Why are you doing things manually? Also, please tag just one version. You confuse matters by including two.

Comment: This is because you gave your body this padding `padding-left: calc(var(--nav-width) + 2rem);`  The white color is the color of your body. Maybe rethink on how to build the base layout for your page.

Comment: Add `background-color: var(--white-color);` to the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go... Comments are added in the snippet below.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

  const showNavbar = (toggleId, navId, bodyId, headerId) => {
    const toggle = document.getElementById(toggleId),
      nav = document.getElementById(navId),
      bodypd = document.getElementById(bodyId),
      headerpd = document.getElementById(headerId)

    // Validate that all variables exist
    if (toggle && nav && bodypd && headerpd) {
      toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
        // show navbar
        nav.classList.toggle('show')
        // change icon
        toggle.classList.toggle('bx-x')
        // add padding to body
        bodypd.classList.toggle('body-pd')
        // add padding to header
        headerpd.classList.toggle('body-pd')
      })
    }
  }

  showNavbar('header-toggle', 'nav-bar', 'body-pd', 'header')

  /*===== LINK ACTIVE =====*/
  const linkColor = document.querySelectorAll('.nav_link')

  function colorLink() {
    if (linkColor) {
      linkColor.forEach(l => l.classList.remove('active'))
      this.classList.add('active')
    }
  }
  linkColor.forEach(l => l.addEventListener('click', colorLink))

  // Your code to run since DOM is loaded and ready
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap");
:root {
  --header-height: 3rem;
  --nav-width: 68px;
  --first-color: #4723D9;
  --first-color-light: #AFA5D9;
  --white-color: #F7F6FB;
  --body-font: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  --normal-font-size: 1rem;
  --z-fixed: 100
}

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: var(--header-height) 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0; /* Change "0 1rem" to "0 0". */
  font-family: var(--body-font);
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  transition: .5s
}

a {
  text-decoration: none
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--header-height);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  background-color: var(--white-color);
  z-index: var(--z-fixed);
  transition: .5s
}

.header_toggle {
  color: var(--first-color);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer
}

.header_img {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden
}

.header_img img {
  width: 40px
}

.l-navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -30%;
  width: var(--nav-width);
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
  padding: .5rem 1rem 0 0;
  transition: .5s;
  z-index: var(--z-fixed)
}

.nav {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: hidden
}

.nav_logo,
.nav_link {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  padding: .5rem 0 .5rem 1.5rem
}

.nav_logo {
  margin-bottom: 2rem
}

.nav_logo-icon {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  color: var(--white-color)
}

.nav_logo-name {
  color: var(--white-color);
  font-weight: 700
}

.nav_link {
  position: relative;
  color: var(--first-color-light);
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  transition: .3s
}

.nav_link:hover {
  color: var(--white-color)
}

.nav_icon {
  font-size: 1.25rem
}

.show {
  left: 0
}

.body-pd {
  padding-left: calc(var(--nav-width) + 1rem)
}

.active {
  color: var(--white-color)
}

.active::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: var(--white-color)
}

.height-100 {
  height: 100vh
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  body {
    margin: calc(var(--header-height) + 1rem) 0 0 0;
    padding-left: calc(var(--nav-width) + 0rem); /* Change "calc(var(--nav-width) + 2rem" to "calc(var(--nav-width) + 0rem". */
  }
  .header {
    height: calc(var(--header-height) + 1rem);
    padding: 0 2rem 0 calc(var(--nav-width) + 2rem)
  }
  .header_img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px
  }
  .header_img img {
    width: 45px
  }
  .l-navbar {
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem 1rem 0 0
  }
  .show {
    width: calc(var(--nav-width) + 156px)
  }
  .body-pd {
    padding-left: calc(var(--nav-width) + 188px)
  }
}


/* Add this. */
#title {
  margin-left: 2rem; /* The same as header padding-left (i.e., 2rem). */
  margin-top: 4rem; /* The same as header height (i.e., 3rem + 1rem). */
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="./css/navlayout.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boxicons@latest/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="icon" href="./img/icon.png" />

  <title>Basic - Bootstrap 5 with Gulp 4</title>
</head>

<body id="body-pd">
  <header class="header" id="header">
    <div class="header_toggle"> <i class='bx bx-menu' id="header-toggle"></i> </div>
    <div class="header_img"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/hczKIze.jpg" alt=""> </div>
  </header>
  <div class="l-navbar" id="nav-bar">
    <nav class="nav">
      <div>
        <a href="#" class="nav_logo"> <i class='bx bx-layer nav_logo-icon'></i> <span class="nav_logo-name">BBBootstrap</span> </a>
        <div class="nav_list">
          <a href="#" class="nav_link active"> <i class='bx bx-grid-alt nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">Dashboard</span> </a>
          <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class='bx bx-user nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">Users</span> </a>
          <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class='bx bx-message-square-detail nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">Messages</span> </a>
          <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class='bx bx-bookmark nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">Bookmark</span> </a>
          <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class='bx bx-folder nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">Files</span> </a>
          <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class='bx bx-bar-chart-alt-2 nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">Stats</span> </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class='bx bx-log-out nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">SignOut</span> </a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <!--Container Main start-->
  <div class="height-100 bg-light">
    <h4 id="title">Main Components</h4>
  </div>
  <!--Container Main end-->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="./js/navlayout.js"></script>
</body>
```